# F# poorly formatted module

Tags: module, f#

Hi what is wrong with my code below, my errors are:
unmatched { which is mostly due to my tabs, 
Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of the form 'seq { ... }'
Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression

```
module records =
   let debate(irthes:DateTime) =
       {
            let mutable manch = nexttime(irthes) 
            let mutable array1: DateTime array = Array.zeroCreate 480
            for i in 0 .. 480-1 do
                Array.set array1 i (manch)
                let next = Array.get array1 i
                let! manch=nexttime(next)
           return(array1)  
       }
```

Comment: Please provide the complete error output you received. When working with an indentation dependent language, if you think there is a problem with the indentation (tabs), then fix that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
module records =
  let debate(irthes:DateTime) =
    let mutable manch = nexttime(irthes) 
    let array1: DateTime array = Array.zeroCreate 480
    for i in 0 .. 480-1 do
      array1.[i] <- manch
      manch <- nexttime manch
    array1
```

Here are things that were wrong with the code:

- You are not using computation expressions (like asynchronous workflows), so there is no need to wrap things in curly brackets.
- To return a value you do not need `return`. Just use the value as the last expression of the body
- The `let!` construct does not mean *assign*. It has a fairly special meaning in computation expressions. To mutate `manch`, you can write `manch <- nexttime(next)`.
- Not an error, but you do not need to mark the array as mutable. You are mutating its contents, not the `array1` variable.
- You can make the code nicer by using `arr.[i] <- v` to write to an array and `arr.[i]` to read from an array. I also do not understand why you were reading a value immediately after writing it.

Answer (score 2):

There's not that much that's even valid about what you're trying to do. First off, it seems you're trying to initialize a record -- to do so, you have to assign the fields to values with `=`, like so:

```
type Person = { name: string; address: string }
let joe = { name = "Joe Smith"; address: "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, 20500" }
```

Also, F# doesn't have an early exit (`return`); the result of any function/method is simply the result of the last expression:

```
let increment n = n + 1
```

Hence no `return n + 1`. Also, `let!` is only used in computation expressions. However, if you want to mutate a variable, `foo` for example, to 42, use `foo <- 42`. One last thing that I see: the line with `return(array1)` is lacking another space of indentation -- it really matters!

It looks like you might be copy-pasting code without knowing what any of it means -- that doesn't often work out too well. If this is the case, try to understand exactly how certain features in F# work by testing them out yourself. It'll go a lot smoother in the long run.